# Paste values in a filtered table in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste values in specific sheet in a table that I have in a different sheet.

I have to filter the table by the sheet name and then paste the values I copied before in the column "D".

The problem is that it pastes the values in the first row and no in the first filtered row of column "D"

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Sub copia()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim hotel As String
    
    hotel = ActiveSheet.Name
         
    Sheets("discounts").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("discount").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=hotel
    
    Sheets(hotel).Select
    Range("d43:d50").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Sheets("discounts").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("discount").ListColumns(4).Range.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets(hotel).Select
    Range("L33").Select
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Your code first does filtering on a table, then selects and copies some values in one COLUMN (not ROW), then you come back and select ANOTHER column (including values which were NOT filtered) and finally paste. Do you intentionally copy ant paste columns? You filter rows, so maybe you need to copy and paste rows?.. Please describe what you want to do more precisely.

Comment: Hello @ZygD. Thanks for your comment. What I do is filter in a table by the sheet name, the filter is in column 1. Then I go back to the original sheet and select some values that have to be paste in the column 4 of the table. This values have to be paste in the column that is already filtered, but everytime I run the code they are paste in the first row, that is not filtered.

Comment: That looks like a risky way to transfer values - do the copied values need to line up with each destination row?

Comment: The fact that you filter your table beforehand does nothing. When after that you select the 4th column it selects all the 4th column (even filtered out rows). This is why you get values pasted beginning the first table's data row. It is not a safe way, because you may sometimes not know how many rows will be filtered while your "d43:d50" (8 rows) is always constant. I believe you would want to make "d43:d50" dynamic too. Think about it. What if you filter only 2 rows while you paste 8 rows? What if you filter 20 rows while pasting 8.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @TimWilliams. Yes, they have to be line up with each destination row.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ZygD. They are going to be always 8 rows. By the way, Its a way of do it dynamic¿?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
Sub copia()
    Dim hotel As String
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim rTarget As Range
    Dim cellTarget As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    hotel = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set rSource = Sheets(hotel).Range("d43:d50")
    Set rTarget = Sheets("discounts").ListObjects("discount").DataBodyRange
    
    i = 1
    For Each cellTarget In rTarget.Parent.Range(rTarget.Columns(4).Address)
      If cellTarget.Offset(, -3) = hotel Then cellTarget = rSource(i)
      i = i + 1
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI `rTarget.Parent.Range(rTarget.Columns(4).Address)` is the same as `rTarget.Columns(4)`

Comment: @TimWilliams - I thought so too, but while testing I was proved wrong...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Still don´t work :(

Comment: In my test case it worked. If it doesn't for you, you would need to share more details like screenshots of your data and everything else what you think would be useful.

Comment: What is the name of the "hotel" sheet?